# Switch case inside a loop inside a switch case

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement, c99

A friend of mine has just joked that this would be possible in C, to which I responded: impossible. It turned out it is possible and compiles without ANY warnings.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(){

    int x = 1;

    switch(x) {
        case 1: 
            printf("1\n");

            while(1) {
                case 2:
                    printf("bad 2\n");          
            }
            break;

        default:
            printf("default\n");
            break;          
    }

}
```

Setting `x` to 1 or 2 results in an infinite loop printing `bad 2` all the time.

Why? What is going on, how is this even legal???

I am using GCC 4.8.2, Windows, `-std=c99` ...

---

**Edit:** This question is about why is it legal, if it is legal, and since when. Examples are nice, but not the goal of my question. I'd like to know, if this whole placing of `case` labels anywhere is a conscious C design, or an accident, or a leaky abstraction / implementation detail leak ?

Comment: Oh Duff, where for art thou?

Answer (score 2):

This is legal. The depending part of a `switch` is in fact just an arbitrary statement or block, and the `case` and `default` labels have just to fulfill the rules of other labels, namely to prefix a statement.

In the example you are giving this makes not much sense, but there are examples, namely the notorious Duff's device that use this kind of features.

Comment: Yeah, I'll read about Duff's in  moment, but will treat is an example only. What I am asking is generally, if this was legal C (since when? since always?) and, perhaps, why is this legal? Java would never permit to write such code - switch/case is a separate constuct, whereas here in C, it seems (please confirm), that case is just a label?

Comment: @Parobay, I did reply to that no? It is complying with the C standard, and this with any of its version. To your question "why?", my guess would be that C is thought to be a simple language, syntactically. The dependent construct is a statement or block as for any of the other control structures.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device#Mechanism this is pretty nice

Answer (score 0):

The standard example/explanation of this is Duff's device: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)

I suggest you read the article and then ask a refined question if there are still unclear areas.

Answer (score 0):

Is this legal? Yes it is because syntactically, you may nest a case as many levels deep as you want inside a switch. This is perfectly legal:

```
switch(a)
{
case 1: break;
{ 
    {
        case 2: break;
    }
}
}
```

And a while() can be used in place of any statement. The compiler doesn't bother to check what is inside as long as they are all valid C statements.